# Como remover parte de um arquivo JSON

Tags: python, json, conversão-de-tipo

Preciso remover partes de um JSON, porém não sei como posso fazer

Estou convertendo o mesmo para CSV, e quando converto a estrutura fica toda estranha

Segue print explicando melhor, o que está marcado em preto, preciso remover e o que está em vermelho preciso manter.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue json referente o que preciso converter:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"url requisição",
    "value":[
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":51,
            "cprq_object_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":52,
            "cprq_object_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":54,
            "cprq_object_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":72,
            "cprq_object_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":73,
            "cprq_object_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        }
    ]
}
```

E também o script python que uso pra converter:

```
import csv
import json
infile = open("nomejson.json","r")
outfile = open("nomecsv.csv","w")

writer = csv.writer(outfile)

for row in json.loads(infile.read()):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Pelo celular eu não consigo ver o que está no print. Tem como por no texto da pergunta o texto que você grifou na imagem?

Comment: Então na verdade identifiquei outro problema ele está colocando umas barras no json que não aparecem no output do console, por isso o formato do json fica ruim. Estranho

Comment: Então o erro não é reproduzível? Deve ser fechado por "erro de digitação"? Ou então isso merece que você mesmo responda

Comment: Não é digitação, no output do python ele funciona normal, porém quando mando pro json ele ficar com as barras ( '\' )

Comment: então creio que você deva responder

Comment: @Lacobus, talvez as contrabarras sejam literais? Vide comentários  anteriores do AP

Comment: Então elas aparecem quando executo os seguintes comandos:                

with open(view+'.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(r.text, outfile)

Answer (score 4):

**json2csv.py:**

```
import csv
import json

# Abre arquivo de entrada para leitura
with open("entrada.json", "r") as infile:

    # Carrega arquivo JSON de entrada
    data = json.load( infile )

# Abre arquivo de saida para gravacao
with open("saida.csv", "wb") as outfile:

    # Cria gravador de CSV...
    wr = csv.writer( outfile, delimiter=',' )

    # Para cada elemento da array "value"
    for item in data["value"]:

        # Escreve cabecalho somente na primeira iteracao
        if( data["value"].index(item) == 0 ):
            wr.writerow(item.keys())

        # Escreve linha com os dados
        wr.writerow(item.values())
```

**entrada.json**:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"https://jnj-dev-pilot.csod.com/services/api/x/odata/api/views/#vw_rpt_cert_prerequisite",
    "value":[
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":51,
            "cprq_object_id":"d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":52,
            "cprq_object_id":"20ca15ff-7c6f-4938-a00a-7f17a2753a7b",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":54,
            "cprq_object_id":"d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":72,
            "cprq_object_id":"d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        },
        {
            "cprq_cert_id":73,
            "cprq_object_id":"d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08",
            "cprq_cert_cert_id":0
        }
    ]
}
```

**saida.csv**:

```
cprq_cert_id,cprq_cert_cert_id,cprq_object_id
51,0,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08
52,0,20ca15ff-7c6f-4938-a00a-7f17a2753a7b
54,0,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08
72,0,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08
73,0,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08
```

Comment: Muito bom, o problema agora está sendo na hora de gerar o json que não vem exatamente nesse formato, mas vou abrir outro tópico pra tratar essa questão. Obrigado @lacobus!

Comment: Lacobus: Cool!! +1

Answer (score 0):

(não é bem uma resposta mas uma nota) Usando o `csvkit`:

```
$ in2csv -Ik value outro.json 
cprq_cert_id,cprq_object_id,cprq_cert_cert_id
51,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08,0
52,20ca15ff-7c6f-4938-a00a-7f17a2753a7b,0
54,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08,0
72,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08,0
73,d0b7fae2-cc11-44d1-a45b-a39642e65c08,0
```